# How to keeping abstract class in Proguard, (JedisPubSub)

Tags: java, proguard, jedis

Currently, I try obfuscated java code use the Proguard

In the existing code, code was implemented inside the subscribe, but after obfuscation, the codes disappear.

```
origin source
======================
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("test_host", 9999);
jedis.subscribe(new JedisPubSub() {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(String channel, String message) {
        // do something job ..
        System.out.println(String.format("channel : %s, message : %s", channel, message));
    }
},"test channel");
```

```
obfuscation after
======================
this.c.subscribe((JedisPubSub)new Object(this, jsonParser), new String[] { "test channel" });
```

I tried changing Proguard options.

```
-keep public class redis.clients.jedis.JedisPubSub
-keep, allowobfuscation class redis.clients.jedis.JedisPubSub
etc ....
```

How can i keep origin format ??

Comment: can you add the command that you run to obfuscate your java code?

Comment: @KamèlRomdhani I don't have run code, I useing Proguard gui tool

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue.

The reason why, i added jar only ${java_home}/jre/lib/rt.jar

```
-libraryjars ${my_java_home}/jre/lib/rt.jar
```

After the many try, realize i need jedis.jar and another jars.

so I added

```
-libraryjars ${my_java_home}/jre/lib/rt.jar
-libraryjars ${my_jedis_jar_path}/jedis-3.0.1.jar
...
...
```